# how to search a list elements in a file and then write it to another file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of two elements and i want to search list elements in a file.
The list and the file is below:
list a:
[subscriber,rate,exchange]
and file b:
postsubscriber are given as required.
postrate is clear